# Javascript/React map unique json names to buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, dictionary

I have the following JSON

```
[
{"location":"2034","type":"Residential","price":400000,"address":"123 Fake Street","suburb":"Maroubra","historical_DAs":0,"description":"Residential","property_ID":1},
{"location":"2036","type":"Commercial","price":475000,"address":"123 Fake Street","suburb":"Coogee","historical_DAs":10,"description":"Government","property_ID":2},
{"location":"2035","type":"Food & Bev","price":56000,"address":"123 Fake Street","suburb":"Clovelly","historical_DAs":3,"description":"Residential","property_ID":3},
{"location":"2031","type":"Education","price":69070,"address":"123 Fake Street","suburb":"Randwick","historical_DAs":7,"description":"Government","property_ID":4},
{"location":"2036","type":"Education","price":69070,"address":"123 Fake Street","suburb":"Randwick","historical_DAs":7,"description":"Government","property_ID":5}
```

]

And I want to take the unique values in the 'description' field and map them to some buttons.

I have looked at other answers and have created the following:

> const uniqueDescription = [...new Set(info.map(item =>
> item.description))];   console.log(uniqueDescription);

Which provides the 2 unique values I want, I am unsure how to place them into button components using props.

I have a function called TypeButtons:

```
    function TypeButtons({uniqueDescriptions}) {
    return (
        <div>
             <div>
                 <div className="hidden lg:inline-flex mb-1 px-9">     
                <button      
                 className="button"
                 onClick={() => {placeholder}}
                 key={id}
                 >
                    {uniqueDescriptions}
                 </button>        
             </div>
             </div>
   </div>
    )
        }
export default TypeButtons
```

Which is then passed through to another component and renders it like so:

```
  <div className="hidden lg:inline-flex mb-1 px-2">
      {/* Mapping in the unique descriptions */}
      {uniqueDescription?.map(({item}) => (
     <TypeButtons
       uniqueDescriptions={uniqueDescription} 
     />
     ))}
```

What I end up with is the following:
[image]

It is creating two buttons, which is correct, but with both unique values in both buttons.

How do I display the two unique values in two unique buttons?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whe this code run

```
const uniqueDescription = [...new Set(info.map(item =>
item.description))]; console.log(uniqueDescription);
```

uniqueDescription variable has an array value

```
["Residential", "Government"]
```

and in this code u dont need destructive item

```
  {uniqueDescription?.map(({item}) => (
     <TypeButtons
       uniqueDescriptions={uniqueDescription} 
     />
     ))}
```

so just do like this

```
  {uniqueDescription?.map((item) => (
     <TypeButtons
       uniqueDescriptions={uniqueDescription} 
     />
     ))}
```

[if u need example, u can see this code](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-pasteur-odxk14?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

`uniqueDescriptions` is an array with two items in it. If you interpolate the array into the JSX like you're doing, the result will be both array items joined together by a comma.

```
{uniqueDescriptions}
```

That's not what you want. You need to reference the *item being iterated over* in the array. Change the signature of `TypeButtons` so that its prop is named, say, `description` (singular), and then do:

```
{uniqueDescription?.map(description => (
  <TypeButtons
    description={description}
  />
))}
```

You also don't need to destructure anything when mapping over `uniqueDescription`, because it's an array of strings, not an array of objects.